# Yitroh's Advise to Moses - What's the Chiddush?

Tags: beit-din-court, parashas-yisro

Bney Noah are commanded on Dinim, that is establishing a legal system and courts. I would expect the Israelites in Egypt and through the Exodus to comply with this commandment and have already established a system of legal courts.

Moreover, in Marah the were explicitly commanded Dinim (civil laws) that should include all the details on proper legal system, including number of judges and number of Batei Dinim.

**What novelty did Yitro advise Moses on establishing courts for Israel?**

Answer (score 3):

Moshe Rabbeinu assumed the task of dinim on his own. Yisro criticized him for this, instructing him instead to delegate.